# How can I get Ptr of a ByteString?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Is there a way to extract underlying direct pointer to memory off the ByteString object?
My current approach is incorrect, compiler says.

```hs
getPtr :: ByteString -> Ptr Word8
getPtr (PS ptr _ _) = ptr
```

Comment: It seems that ByteString.Internal does not export the constructor `PS` (with good reason!), so indeed you cannot pattern match on it.  Why exactly do you want to get the pointed to the ByteString object?  If we know that it will be easier to know how to help.

Comment: `.Internal` does export `PS`. danbst: When asking a question, please include the full code and full error message so that people don't have to guess at what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`unsafeUseAsCString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeUseAsCString) from `Data.ByteString.Unsafe`. It has type:

```
ByteString -> (CString -> IO a) -> IO a
```

You *could* use `unsafeUseAsCString bs return` to simply get the pointer, but this is highly unsafe because the `ByteString` isn’t guaranteed not to move, and the memory may be freed at any point after the `CString -> IO a` function terminates, so you should only access the pointer within it; internally it uses `Foreign.ForeignPtr.withForeignPtr`, which *pins* the memory so it won’t move if a GC happens. Per the docs:

> The memory may freed at any point after the subcomputation terminates, so the pointer to the storage must *not* be used after this.

The string also won’t be null-terminated unless the `ByteString` happened to be, and it will have type `CString` (that is, `Ptr CChar`) instead of `Ptr Word8`, but you can use `castPtr` from `Foreign.Ptr` to get around that if it’s a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I could not imagine, that pattern match can cause impurity in some cases, so I didn't look through _unsafe_ functions.

Comment: @danbst: Well, actually *getting* the pointer is pure. But it is impure to pass the pointer to a C function that may mutate it. If you know that such a function is pure, that’s what `unsafePerformIO` is for. It’s a promise to the type system that you know a fact, even though it can’t be proven.